# Css transition div shaking

Tags: css, html

Why when I use position absolute and percentage width I have this glitch when I hover on div  above?
There is example. I have this glitch on little more complicated site.

```
<div class="box"> text </div>

<div class="container">


<div>

.box {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: red;
}
.box:hover {
    transition: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 6px);

}
.container {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    width:40%;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    background: blue;
    color:white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TsUEH/

When you hover on red text then width of blue div are shaking.
How can i avoid this without removing percentage and position absolute?

Comment: It seems fine to me. Tested with Chrome 33. However you might want to use `transition` property on the `.box` selector instead.

Comment: I found some errors into your code. Is this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mju5J/1/) works better ?

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedback! I see now It seems this shaking its only when chrome window is zoomed in. I haved it 150% zoomed and only then shaking problem appears.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It works fine for me, but if you find an element "shaking" (esp in Chrome), it's likely because of the `translate` function not working with the z-index correctly

If you need to fix it, you can use this code (lifesaver):

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: Thank you, i see now it seems that shaking problem only appears when chrome window is zoomed in for 150%. But it seems that when i add your code to child element it works and its not shaking! :) Its good practice to set it in this case?

Comment: Yep you can set that whenever you want - it's a good bit of code to help keep everything working. If you find particular elements are still shaking, you should apply the code to those elements individually! Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much one more time :)

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Thank you so much! I only see this shaking happening in Firefox though.

Comment: This css properties has made the text blur

Comment: @RichardPeck it amazes me 9 years later your solution is still necessary and that browsers haven't completely eliminated glitches like this! Given how this problem doesn't seem to be going away, would you be able to share a little more background on this subject of z-index malfunctioning, such as why it happens and why it's still an issue today? I can't find deeper articles explaining it and it's a very annoying and unpredictable issue. Sort of killing all the fun with CSS for me ;)