# Why does absolutely positioned container cause its children to shake while animating?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

Consider the following demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/p1n3j7cv/

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}

a .outer {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  min-height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: min-height 3s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

a .inner {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
}

a:hover .outer {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="">

  <p> Some regular text <br> which spans <br> multiplle lines <br> so that we have <br> lorem ipsum
  </p>
  <span class="outer">
    <span class="inner">
        hello
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

When you hover over the grey block you will see, as the outer span is expanding(transition), the orange span shakes. This happens on all major browsers. The reason seem to be the absolute positioning involved, If I didn't any content on the back, I could get away with *flex*, without using absolute position, which solves the problem. But for my project I need absolute positioning. I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22423176/3429430), but it didn't work.

My guess is it has something to do with not using gpu accelration while animating `min-height`. Every pixel transition might be doing css repaint, which further recalculate absolute positioned elements position on every pixel movement.

Question: Why is the shaking happening at all?

Answer (score 1):

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}

a .outer {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  min-height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: min-height 3s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index:1

}
a .inner {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  z-index:2
}

a:hover .outer {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <span class="outer"></span>
  <span class="inner">hello</span>
</a>
```

Comment: What I could think out is to get the '.inner' out of the translation so it no need to be resized. Please not you shouldn't put a paragraph into a anchor tag.

Comment: This is basically, what I ended up doing in my project. The problem with this solution for me is, I don't have fixed heights on my `.outer` and `.inner`.  The content(_hello_ in our example) is dynamic. So, I had to repeat all of the content in `.outer` as well.

Comment: Fixed heights don't bother vertical centering. I think I don't get the problem.

Comment: This answer would be better if it included some explanation of the changes.

Comment: @Azu I happen to have icons and lines of text, the text is dynamic and can span to two lines, so assigning fixed height is not an option for me.